# Use here document with ENTRYPOINT/CMD in Dockerfile

Tags: bash, shell, docker, dockerfile

## What I want to do

My goal is to end up with a Docker image which - as soon as a container is launched from it - reads input from stdin until it meets EOF. Then, it simply writes back what has been read to stdout.

Basically, my idea was this should be possible by using the here document syntax `cat << EOF`.

## What I did so far

So far, I tried different variants with the CMD Dockerfile instruction but had no success until now. From all the images I've created I launched containers with `docker run -it myimage` to keep the container's stdin attached.

#### Variant 1

```
 FROM alpine 3.7
 CMD ["cat", "<<", "EOF"]
```

This leads to the following error:

```
cat: can't open '<<': No such file or directory
cat: can't open 'EOF': No such file or directory
```

#### Variant 2

```
 FROM alpine 3.7
 CMD ["cat << EOF"]
```

Result:

```
 container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"cat << EOF\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

#### Variant 3

```
 FROM alpine:3.7
 CMD ["sh", "-c", "cat << EOF"]
```

Result:

This does nothing but returns immediately.

#### Variant 4

```
 FROM alpine: 3.7
 CMD "cat << EOF"
```

Result:

```
 /bin/sh: cat << EOF: not found
```

## What I expect

I'm searching for a solution that behaves like described above. The following `docker run` command works perfectly, but I'd like to define this as the default entry point for my Docker image:

```
 $ docker run -it alpine cat << EOF
 > Hello Docker
 > EOF
 Hello Docker
```

Comment: Support for heredocs in Dockerfiles is a long-standing feature request but it's still not supported.  https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1554 is horrible because people insist on piling on more `+1` comments instead of just using the "thumbs up" on an existing comment to voice their support for this enhancement.

Comment: Thx, I already came across this discussion, but still thought there must be a way to use here-docs for ENTRYPOINT or CMD. I'm actually surprised it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can't work because the shell parses the command line, including the heredoc *before* it executes it.

Basically you can just do this:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM xyz
# cat reads from stdin by default if no filename gets passed to it
CMD 'cat'
```

Build and run the container:

```
docker build -t foo .
docker run -ti foo
HelloDocker
HelloDocker
```

You stop the input with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (That's literally EOF)

---

PS: If you want to use a here-doc, run the above container like this:

```
docker run -i foo <<EOF
Hello Docker
EOF

Hello Docker
```

Comment: Thx, the second one is a great idea. It seems kinda weird to me that I can pass the here-doc on the command line, but that the same thing does not work with CMD. Actually, I'd at least have expected the shell form to work.

Comment: Well, also on the command line you can't run `bash -c 'cat <<EOF'`. That's just syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Right. I just wondered why `sh -c cat << EOF` in the terminal works while `CMD "cat << EOF"` in a Dockerfile doesn't. Was not aware that this get's evaluated to `sh -c 'cat << EOF'`.